# How to have a inner Join on datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we have a inner join on two datatables in .Net 2.0.
Say I have a datatable dt1 and dt2 . I want to have a inner join on the and dump the result in dt3.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, generate the datatable from a SQL JOIN statement in the first place. It'll be significantly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define a [`DataRelation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx) between the two.

```
private void CreateRelation() 
{
    // Get the DataColumn objects from two DataTable objects 
    // in a DataSet. Code to get the DataSet not shown here.
    DataColumn parentColumn = 
        DataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustID"];
    DataColumn childColumn = 
        DataSet1.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustID"];
    // Create DataRelation.
    DataRelation relCustOrder;
    relCustOrder = new DataRelation("CustomersOrders", 
        parentColumn, childColumn);
    // Add the relation to the DataSet.
    DataSet1.Relations.Add(relCustOrder);
}
```